# sql server 2014 Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2014

I am using sql sever 2014. i am need to export data sql server to excel.

so i tried like this

```
CREATE TABLE OI_TEMP
(
 OI_NAME      TEXT
 ,OI_ADDRESSS  TEXT
)

INSERT INTO OI_TEMP (OI_NAME,OI_ADDRESSS) VALUES('AA','BBB')

 insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\testing.xlsx;', 
'SELECT OI_NAME,OI_ADDRESSS FROM [Sheet1$]') select OI_NAME,OI_ADDRESSS from OI_TEMP
```

but is not working..
its show `Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".`

i am searching here but answer not working for me.. What am doing wrong?
And i have another doubt can i possible to insert record in specif row in excel??

am using **sql sever 2014**.

Its Working in **SQl SERVER 2008** but not working in  **SQL SERVER  2014**....what am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the data provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 installed on your server.
You need to install Access DB runtime